# Unity assets store defense

Tags: security, unity-game-engine, assets

I am making asset for assets story. I want sell it there.

But my assets most consist of scripts. Anyone can buy it and after a litle modify  put in a assets store.
How can I defense it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no way to fully prevent it, but the Asset Store use terms got you covered:

http://unity3d.com/company/legal/as_terms

Section 2.2 of "End User's Rights and Obligations"

*Licensor grants to the END-USER a non-exclusive, worldwide, and perpetu- al license to the Asset to integrate Assets only as incorporated and embed- ded components of electronic games and interactive media and distribute such electronic game and interactive media. END-USER may otherwise not reproduce, distribute, sublicense, rent, lease or lend the Assets.*

If you discorver someone has in fact modified and is reselling your work, you have the legal upper hand.